# I don't see any difference between lightmap resolutions

Tags: unreal-engine4, light

In my project, I have an issue with blurry shadows.

I created a test project from a Third Person template and tried to make the shadows sharper and more blurry. The only way to do that that I found in Google was to increase the lightmap resolution, but I don't see any difference except for building time and memory usage.

The level has a Stationary light source and I've tested it with 4, 512 and 4096 resolutions.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Lightmap Res 4]

[image: Lightmap Res 512]

[image: Lightmap Res 4096]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! All the static Actors in the ThirdPerson template override the lightmap resolution of the StaticMesh.

[image]